# Proper MySQL query to accurately collate file download statistics

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to serve MP3 files for a podcast. Amazon provides access logs, which I'm fetching and storing in a MySQL database. The database looks like this:

```
request_id  varchar(16)
time        int(10)     
file        varchar(255)        
sent        bigint(20)      
size        bigint(20)      
status      smallint(5)     
ip          varchar(39)         
referrer    varchar(255)        
user_agent  varchar(255)
```

Because this is a podcast, a huge number of hits are 206 range requests (from iTunes/iOS), requesting each file in small chunks.

I also have some people downloading the file more than once.

So what I am trying to do is construct a query which:

- provides only one result per-file, per-IP (so each IP/person can only count as one "hit" for each file).
- sums the total of all bytes sent (`sent` column) per file/IP so I can see what the total of all the range requests for that particular file/IP combination was.
- BONUS: compares the summed total of the `sent` column per file/IP and only returns that result if that sum total of bytes is >= 75% of the `size` column (currently I'm doing this comparison post-query with PHP).

Here's what I'm using currently, which I *believe* is working, but the complete ramifications of `GROUP BY` are a mystery to me (for example - does the column order in `GROUP BY` matter?):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%M %D') as date, ip, file, SUM(sent) as sent, size
FROM stats
WHERE sent > 0 
AND size > 0
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-09-01'
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2012-09-30'
GROUP BY ip, file
ORDER BY time ASC, file ASC
```

Anyone see any potential pitfalls here?

Comment: Your query is not going to work because you did not include non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: two questions: 1- does size have a constant value across all rows that have the same file ? 2- a user can download the same file on two or more different dates. does that still count as one hit ? and if it does, which date do you want displayed, the most recent ?

Comment: A.J.: `size` does indeed have a constant value, and I do want to restrict each user to one download hit overall, using the earliest date. I think [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12945739/174299) hits these points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to answer your question:

the order of columns in the "group by" does not matter in regard to the content returned back in the result.

you will always get the same grouping and same aggregated values. but it might affect the performance in mysql in case there are indexes on the columns and the order in the group by does not match the order of the columns in the index. I have seen an article once discussing the performance effect. if i find it, i will post its link.

As for your query, please note you are selecting fields that are not part of the group by. this is not a standard of SQL, but MySql allows this (its possible to tell MySql to forbid it). What you need to know is that the engine will make the groups, and for those fields, it will select the first values from the first row that it encounters in the group. the way you have your query, this will not guarantee correct results. the reason is that the order by is applied on the results after they are finished. there are few possible solutions, but i will mention using a sub query and having the order inside to insure the first rows to be the ones you need before the grouping happens.

```
SELECT in_tab.date, in_tab.ip, in_tab.file, SUM(in_tab.sent), in_tab.size
FROM (
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%M %D') as date, ip, file, sent, size
  FROM stats
  WHERE sent > 0 
  AND size > 0
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-09-01'
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2012-09-30'
  ORDER BY time ASC
) in_tab
GROUP BY in_tab.ip, in_tab.file
ORDER BY in_tab.date ASC, in_tab.file ASC
```

As you can see, the order in the sub query is performed before the grouping starts. so in each group made by the outer query, the fields date and size will be taken from the first row, one that will have earliest date (if you want most recent, change to DESC in the subquery). the outer order by is used to sort the final results and you can change it as you wish.

Now for the BONUS: in order to only those results where the sum is >= 75% of the size, you can use the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT in_tab.date, in_tab.ip, in_tab.file, SUM(in_tab.sent) as total_sent, in_tab.size
FROM (
  SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time,'%M %D') as date, ip, file, sent, size
  FROM stats
  WHERE sent > 0 
  AND size > 0
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-09-01'
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2012-09-30'
  ORDER BY time ASC
) in_tab
GROUP BY in_tab.ip, in_tab.file
HAVING total_sent > = 0.75 * in_tab.size
ORDER BY in_tab.date ASC, in_tab.file ASC
```

I would suggest to you to consider the best solution: switching to standard sql. it is better and safer on the long term. then, you would group the wanted data in one query and get the other info (like file size and min/max date) in another query (or using joins). the answer is already very long i will have to stop from explaining and giving examples on that.

Comment: Excellent, thanks A.J., for the query and the explanation. I think this did the trick. A couple of changes I made: additionally selected `time` directly in the subquery and used that in my final `ORDER BY` (as the formatted date orders incorrectly); grouped by `file` first, then `ip` as per [Michael's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12945261/174299); and removed the space in the `HAVING` operator (`>=`, not `> =`).

Answer (score 0):

Group by column order does matter, it groups it by the first column, and then by the next so a group by A, B would group results as A then group on B, which matters if B is similar data.